# Openstreetmap-carto style with Tilemill - unknown black line in streets

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, osm2pgsql

There is an unknown black line in the center of about 80% streets. I have been adjusting line-widths and switching off and on every line layer for hours to no avail.

I am using the latest version of TileMill with the latest openstreetmap-carto style and postgresql. I posted an image below for an example of the black lines that are in the center of the roads. The export looks terrible with these black lines present. I searched for a "road-centerline" style but there were none present that I could find.

[image: example]

---

I narrowed it down to the layer it is on, #roads-text-name.
I'm having an issue though trying to figure out which styling is causing the black lines.

```
    roads-text-name {
  [highway = 'motorway'],
  [highway = 'trunk'],
  [highway = 'primary'] {
    [zoom >= 13] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      [tunnel = 'no'] {
        text-halo-radius: 1;
        [highway = 'motorway'] { text-halo-fill: @motorway-fill; }
        [highway = 'trunk'] { text-halo-fill: @trunk-fill; }
        [highway = 'primary'] { text-halo-fill: @primary-fill; }
      }
    }
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-size: 10;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'secondary'] {
    [zoom >= 13] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @secondary-fill; 
    }
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-size: 10;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'tertiary'],
  [highway = 'tertiary_link'] {
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @tertiary-fill;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'proposed'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-opacity: 0.3;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'construction'] {
    [int_construction_minor = 'no'][zoom >= 13],
    [int_construction_minor = 'yes'][zoom >= 14] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      [zoom >= 17] {
        text-size: 11;
      }
    }
  }
  [highway = 'residential'],
  [highway = 'unclassified'],
  [highway = 'road'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @residential-fill;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
      text-spacing: 400;
    }
  }

  [highway = 'raceway'],
  [highway = 'service'] {
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      [highway = 'raceway'] { text-halo-fill: @raceway-fill; }
      [highway = 'service'] { text-halo-fill: @service-fill; }
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }

  [highway = 'living_street'],
  [highway = 'pedestrian'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      [highway = 'living_street'] { text-halo-fill: @living-street-fill; }
      [highway = 'pedestrian'] { text-halo-fill: @pedestrian-fill; }
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to start at Zoom level 13

Comment: How does the tagging differ between streets having a black line and streets that don't?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out, hah. I can't figure out what layer the black lines are

Comment: Then please tell us the area from your screenshot, ideally with a link to http://openstreetmap.org. Then it is very easy to take a look at the corresponding tags.

Comment: Here is the link to the area of the screenshot http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/38.3396/-79.1266

Comment: It seems to correlate with the [name tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name), see [way 19878352](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/19878352) and [way 19858719](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/19858719). There must be some rule in your stylesheet for drawing roads with a name tag in a special way.

Answer (score 2):

You might find posting on the [OpenStreetMap Carto issue tracker](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues) helpful. Most of the developers have moved from Tilemill to [Kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik), but both should work fine with the style, and because both use Mapnik and carto, both should reproduce the same bugs.

If turning off the `roads-text-name` layer fixes it, that is odd.

I would first update to the latest OpenStreetMap Carto version, as the roads styling has been significantly changed. It's also worth double-checking that turning off the layer is the **only** change that you did, because I see nothing in the code you posted or [the current code](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/884b04b5d5c16b559894f01fb546c5716a4dfc29/roads.mss#L2561-L2709) that would cause carto to generate a linesymbolizer, which is what would draw a line like that.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late response, I kind of got sidetracked from this project. Is there a version of Kosmtik that would work with windows?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the mss, it's difficult to tell. But how about looking at this from a different angle? Rather than *black lines*, do you think the roads have *thick yellow casing*? Are there casing rules for these types of roads?  See "Compound line styles" on https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-lines/